# Not able to get the Certificate Chain while exporting an End Entity X.509 Certificate generated using Bouncy Castle in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pem, pki

I have generated an X509 Certificate like this:

```java
public static X509Certificate createEndEntity(
    X509Certificate signerCert, PrivateKey signerKey,
    String sigAlg, PublicKey certKey)
  throws CertIOException, OperatorCreationException, CertificateException
{
  X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("CN=End Entity");

 
  X509v3CertificateBuilder  certBldr = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(
      signerCert.getSubjectX500Principal(),
      calculateSerialNumber(),
      calculateDate(0),
      calculateDate(24 * 31),
      subject,
      certKey);

 
  certBldr.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints,
          true, new BasicConstraints(false))
      .addExtension(Extension.keyUsage,
          true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature));

 
  ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(sigAlg)
                  .setProvider("BC").build(signerKey);

 
  JcaX509CertificateConverter converter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC");

 
  return converter.getCertificate(certBldr.build(signer));
}
```

And exported it to a PEM format like this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JcaPEMWriter jpw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);
jpw.writeObject(certificate);
jpw.flush();
String pem = sw.toString();
```

Still, the generated certificate doesn't include the certificate Chain to the Root Certificate, and the Signer in the Signature is showing as Unknown.

P.S. : I have already imported Root CA separately in XCA prior to generation. The signer in the Signature is showing as unknown.
[image]

Comment: The Algorithm that is being used is SHA256WITHECDSA

Comment: Of course it doesn't since you only wrote out a single certificate. If you want the other certificates in the chain in the same file then write them out too.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk How should I do that? Should I add a second certificate during the Export using JcaPEMWriter? Any resources I can refer to?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I tried to write both certificates by creating a list and writing using JcaPEMWriter over a loop and the exported string had 2 certificates. While opening it in XCA, it only recognized the first one and the Certificate Chain is still not recognizing the root CA which I have already imported separately previously.